# How to make SVG with small rectangles more visible in react

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have The data bellow

A big rectangular canvas of `width = 100` and `height = 100`

And a set of small rectangles each has an `x` and `y` coordinates, a `width` and a `height`

```
const data = [
    { x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10 },
    { x: 10, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20 },
    { x: 30, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30 },

  ];
```

I drew this `SVG` with the data

```
 <div>
      <svg transform="rotate(180)" width={width} height={height}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <rect key={index} x={item.x} y={item.y} width={item.width} height={item.height} 
          strokeWidth="2" fill="none" stroke="black"></rect>
        ))}
      </svg>
    </div>
```

The SVG is barely visible due to the small lengths, how can i make it more visible without changing the data.

**Image**

[image]

**full code**

```
import React from "react";

const Drawing = () => {

  const data = [
    { x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10 },
    { x: 10, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20 },
    { x: 30, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30 },

  ];
  const width = 100;
  const height = 100;

  return (
    <div>
      <svg transform="rotate(180)" width={width} height={height}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <rect key={index} x={item.x} y={item.y} width={item.width} height={item.height} 
          strokeWidth="2" fill="none" stroke="black"></rect>
        ))}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Drawing;
```

Comment: You may want to use a viewBox attribute for the svg like `viewBox="0 0 60 60"`. Also: since the fill and thestroke are the same for all rectangles you can apply those to the svg element instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use viewport of svg, something like this

`<svg height="90" viewBox='0 0 100 100'> svg lines </svg>`

You put the viewBox of the svg coordinates, but height and width of the resulting image size

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).